# Finding an order on the set of all bitstrings of length $n$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> I am trying to find an order on the set $S$ of all bitstrings of length $n$ such that there is a formula to find the bitstring at $k^{th}$ position in the order on $S$? I'm looking for an order except for the one that orders strings by decimal value because then the bitstring at $k^{th}$ position is the bitstring that we get by converting $k$ into binary and that's trivial.

My attempt: I was looking at the order where we sort bitstrings first by Hamming weight (i.e. number of ones in the bitstring) and then by decimal value. For example, if $n=3$, then the order is:

$$000,001,010,100,011,101,110,111$$

where we've weight zero string first, then all weight one strings sorted by increasing decimal value, then weight two strings sorted by decimal value and so on. Now, I would like a formula to know the string at $k^{th}$ position in this order. I would have to find the largest $m$ s.t.

$$\sum_{i=0}^{m}\binom{n}{i}\leq k \tag{1}$$

which means that the bitstring at $k^{th}$ position is of weight $m+1$. But finding $m$ that satisfies $(1)$ and then finding the precise bitstring at $k^{th}$ position sounds hard.

> Any ideas about how to find the formula for above order or can we find a completely different order?

Comment: I don't think it helps a lot, but your order is at [OEIS A294648](https://oeis.org/A294648).

Comment: @BillyJoe Thanks, that does help me, it has a recursive formula for elements of that ordering.

Comment: @BillyJoe But the formula doesn't let finding the $k^{th}$ element of the sequence. So I still gotta work on that.